# get number of days from epoch string javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, epoch

firestore is returning epoch strings to me from this variable `current_period_end`. the value is this:

```
063756344778.000000000
```

which returns `Friday, May 11, 3990 3:46:18 PM`

I have this epoch value which returns the current date:

```
1618181473
```

which returns todays current date

I want to basically get how many days are left until `current_period_end`. which would mean taking `current_period_end` and subtracting it from today's date. But it doesn't give me the days in between. How can I do this?

Comment: Do they still have leap years in 3990?? Might have double leaps by then

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why it is going to 3990 in the first place, I am not to worried about that tho bc I only need to get like `May 11 - April 11`. @charlietfl